# Suppress default output of a function in R

Tags: r, default, output

> test <- PLS_glm(y,X,p,modele="pls-glm-logistic", alpha.pvals.expli = 0.05, sparse=TRUE, sparseStop=TRUE)

*****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

Family: binomial

Link function: logit

_***component*_** 1 *_*_

_***component*_** 2 *_*_

_***component*_** 3 *_*_

No more significant predictors (<0.05) found

Warning only 3 components were thus extracted

_***Predicting X without NA neither in X nor in Y*_**

****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*****

***how do I suppress the output that follows PLS_glm function call?***

Answer (score 1):

`PLS_glm` uses `cat` function internally. You can redirect the `cat output` using something like :

```
capture.output(test <- PLS_glm(y,X,p,modele="pls-glm-logistic", 
                               alpha.pvals.expli = 0.05,     
                               sparse=TRUE, sparseStop=TRUE),
               file='NULL')
```

This will redirect the cat messages to a new file named 'NULL'.

PS: as a side note, according to the help it better Use `plsRglm` instead.